# How to create list view with another view inside it?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I want to make some similiar view like this one. title bar with info about "money" or "point" upside, list of upgrades in the middle, and button (not necessary) below.

[image]

I'm able to create the listview by code, but I don't know how to put those title bar.
is there anyway to create layout like above with XML?
I have not yet playing with list activity so I don't really understand about this .
hope for your best answer. sorry for my bad english. thank you :)

Comment: Check this <a href="http://coderzheaven.com/index.php/2011/03/android-image-listview/"> link </a> Hope this will help you

Comment: okay that link is really useful. thank you. anyway one more question here : "your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id “@android:id/list”" <--- is the id must always be "list"?

Comment: Here i am customizing the ListActivity, so i have to give id as @android:id/list....otherwise it wont work. Its there in the developer site

Comment: okay , it run well. so many thanks :)